# How do I use transaction in ModelViewSet of Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I update two models in ModelViewSet. How do I use transaction ?
I know how to use transaction.atomic in django class based view, but don't know in ModelViewSet(and ViewSet) in DRF.

```
# models
class Store(models.Model)
    name = models.TextField()

class Stuff(models.Model)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name='stuffs')
    first_name = models.TextField()
    last_name = models.TextField()

# serializers
class StuffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Stuff
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', )

class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stuffs = StuffSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = Stoer.objects.create(name=validated_data['name']
        for stuff in validated_data['stuffs']
            Stuff.objects.create(store=instance,
                                 first_name=stuff['first_name'],
                                 last_name=stuff['last_name'])
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data['name']
        instance.save()
        for stuff in validated_data['stuffs']
            stuff_instance = Stuff.objects.get(id=stuff['id'])
            stuff_instance.first_name=stuff['first_name']
            stuff_instance.last_name=stuff['last_name']
            stuff_instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'stuffs', )

# ModelViewSet
class StoreViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StoreSerializer
```

Comment: Have you tried using `transaction.atomic` decorator on the `create` or `update` methods?

Comment: @andrey-shipilov You mean add transaction.atomic to  create/update/destroy method in StoreViewSet?

Comment: @e4c5 maybe yes. the best answer of question you introduce will be my solution.

Comment: Yeah that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly